# STM32F3 only boots with ST-Link debugger

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm able to flash the STM32F3 of my custom board with an ST-Link v2 without an issue and the program runs fine (turns on a led). However, if I turn off the power, unplug the ST-Link, then turn the power on again, the program doesn't seem to run: the led is off.

The nRST pin rises to 3.3V (internal pull-up) as soon as I turn the power on and Boot0 stays at 0 as it should (external pull-down). The oscilloscope doesn't show any weird behavior on either pin at boot or after.

Another test I ran is this: I launch the program using the ST-Link, then I unplug the ST-Link without turning the power off. The program keeps running fine, no surprise there. But then, if I manually put nRST to the ground, the program stops and if I then release it, it goes up to 3.3V again because of the pull-up and the program restarts and runs just as before. So the problem really seems to be when I power up the board from scratch. FIY, I use the 5V from a USB connection to get the STM's 3.3V via a Voltage Regulator. I also have an external crystal for the STM's clock, which works fine according to the oscilloscope.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: how are you launching the program using the st-link are you downloading to ram and running in in ram or programming the flash and running it there?  what happens when you press/assert reset with the stlink attached?  what happens if you type the reset command (well assuming telnet to openocd to stlink) with the stlink connected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm using Eclipse and Open-OCD to program the chip. I'm programming the flash and running it there: the debugger shows the program running from address 0x0800000.
If I manually pull reset to the ground while stlink is attached, the program restarts and runs fine.

Comment: what if with the stlink disconnected you press reset after the board is up?  does that change things?

Comment: Nope, once the board is up (without stlink), pulling reset to the ground and releasing it doesn't do anything

Comment: Both reset and boot0 **require** external pull-resistors. Boot0 is read just after POR, and must be low immediately after reset goes high.

Comment: nRST requires an external pull-up resistor? Despite the internal pull-up?

Edit: I've just checked the datasheet again, and it doesn't say an external pull-up is required on nRST. (STM32F303VCT6 datasheet, p92/148)

Comment: @Jeroen3: It is recommended for EMC reasons (together with a small capacitor, but not required!

Answer (score 0):

As It turns out, it was a software issue!
I had a line missing in one of my GPIO's initialization code: I set it as an Output, with a Pull down, but without setting its type to Output-PushPull.
This is supposed to be caught by an ASSERT when I configure the pin, and trigger a BP, but for some reason if didn't when the debugger was connected. Actually it did, once, which is how I found the mistake. It remains a mystery why it ran fine the other times.

Anyway, thanks for the answers, it's working fine now!